# Xcode Swift check if array contains object

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this array :

```
  var preferiti : [ModalHomeLine!] = []
```

I want to check if the array contains the same object.

```
if the object exists {

} else {
  var addPrf = ModalHomeLine(titolo: nomeLinea, link: linkNumeroLinea, immagine : immagine, numero : titoloLinea)
  preferiti.append(addPrf)
}
```

Comment: Which object are you referring to by "the same object"? Are you wanting to check for duplicate objects?

Comment: if  addPrf exist { } else {preferiti.append(addPrf)}

Comment: So you have something like this: `var myArray = [1, 2, 3]` and you would like to check if a number, say, 5 exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it sounds like you want an array without duplicate objects. In cases like this, a `set` is what you want. Surprisingly, Swift doesn't have a set, so you can either create your own or use `NSSet`, which would look something like this:

```
let myset = NSMutableSet()
myset.addObject("a") // ["a"]
myset.addObject("b") // ["a", "b"]
myset.addObject("c") // ["a", "b", "c"]
myset.addObject("a") // ["a", "b", "c"] NOTE: this doesn't do anything because "a" is already in the set.
```

UPDATE:

Swift 1.2 added a set type! Now you can do something like

```
let mySet = Set<String>()
mySet.insert("a") // ["a"]
mySet.insert("b") // ["a", "b"]
mySet.insert("c") // ["a", "b", "c"]
mySet.insert("a") // ["a", "b", "c"] NOTE: this doesn't do anything because "a" is already in the set.
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift has a generic `contains` function:

```
contains([1,2,3,4],0) -> false
contains([1,2,3,4],3) -> true
```

Comment: how to use it in my case ?

Comment: @MassimilianoAllegretti Your code would say `if !contains(perferiti, oggetto){ preferiti.append(addPrf) }`